# Pourquoi le "ph" se prononce-t-il "f" ?

Tags: étymologie, prononciation, orthographe, alphabet, grec

C'est une particularité, en français et en anglais, qui n'existe pas, ou plus, en espagnol ni en italien.

Elle m'est d'autant plus incompréhensible que les mots en "ph" sont dérivés du grec, où une seule lettre suffit (et appelée ... phi).

De plus, je ne vois pas de confusion possible si l'orthographe était modifiée ("orthografe").

Le "th" pourrait de même être remplacé par "t", mais au moins sa prononciation n'est pas illogique. L'allemand l'a fait partiellement sans en souffrir.

Comment: ca me fait souvenir le sujet de "ghoti" https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoti#:~:text=Ghoti%20(prononcer%20%2Ff%C9%AA%CA%83%2F),la%20prononciation%20de%20l'anglais.

Answer (score 10):

On a transcrit le `ϕ` du grec ancien par `ph` en raison de sa prononciation : /pʰ/, soit une [consonne occlusive bilabiale sourde aspirée](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_occlusive_bilabiale_sourde). (Le `p` du français est une consonne occlusive bilabiale sourde simple.)

La prononciation du grec a évolué de /pʰ/ vers /f/, une [consonne fricative labio-dentale sourde](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_fricative_labio-dentale_sourde). (C'est le `f` du français.) D'un point de vue biologique, cela signifie que la position de la lèvre inférieure a évolué : au lieu d'être en contact avec la lèvre supérieure, elle est en contact avec les dents de la machoire supérieure.

En français, on a conservé une transcription proche de l'original grec, conformément aux habitudes de faire apparaître l'étymologie dans l'orthographe. En dehors de l'anglais et du français, la plupart des langues transcrites en caractères latin ont une orthographe essentiellement phonétique et ont donc naturellement adapté la graphie à la prononciation.

Answer (score 3):

**Si ma mémoire est bonne** (je n'ai pas sous la main mes volumes de référence et suis sur un ordinateur dont je n'ai pas l'habitude: le clavier à lui seul me cause problème), les digraphes ph et th ont été utilisés en Latin pour représenter ce qui était en Grec ancien des consonnes *aspirées*. La prononciation moderne est reprise du Latin (qui l'a peut-être emprunté à certains dialectes grecs de l'époque).

En ce qui concerne la réforme de l'orthographe, alors là, je ne vois pas où est la question à laquelle qui que ce soit est sensé pouvoir répondre. Je vais quand même m'avancer à noter que tout système écrit, une fois stabilisé, est fatalement sujet à une très forte tension en faveur du status quo, tension particulièrement forte dans une culture comme la française où l'orthographe est pratiquement fétichisée: je me souviens avoir lu une analyse où on notait que la réforme de l'orthographe est opposée le plus violemment par ceux qui peuvent déjà se servir de leurs connaissances durement acquises (bien que sans réelle valeur, d'une certaine manière, car l'orthographe n'est vraiment dans cette analyse qu'une barrière entre la langue et ses usagers, dixit l'italien et l'espagnol, comme tu le notes) pour gagner une forme d'ascendant sur ceux à qui l'orthographe cause problème.

Comment: Je ne me souviens pas d'avoir jamais lu"ph" ni "th" dans un texte latin, mais il a pu y avoir retranscription, dans des éditions non savantes. Le seul mot que je vois, qui souffrirait, et encore, serait "philtre" devenant filtre. Certainement, l'orthographe est un instrument de ségrégation sociale ; dans un de ses contes désopilants, Alphonse Allais proposait ironiquement d'aller plus loin, de compliquer volontairement l'orthographe, et en donne une démonstration éblouissante. Lapsus : "sensé" n'est pas "censé".

Comment: Une augmentation unaire pour la description des problèmes de la langue. Mais ce n'est pas du fétichisme. Je suis de ceux qui n'ont pas été capables d'expliquer la nouvelle grammaire à sa descendance, qui ont un sourire narquois quand ils voient comment on y dénomme un complément, ils ont aussi essayé de remonter aux sources, aux origines du mot (parfois jusqu'au sanskrit), et ce travail s'est gravé définitivement sous forme d'image de caractères (liées à des émotions) dans l'organisation des neurones, source de la phonation (qui laisse souvent un lourd travail au correcteur du PC)